# How to design db tables that store multiple criteria that describe something meaningful?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I was trying to design tables to store settings like **giving out rewards**. The reward is given need to be **limited based on some criteria**. For example, Children with **2 stars** and **25 points** is rewarded **20 candies** while children with **2 stars** and **70 points** is rewarded **65 candies**.

Here is what I can think out of:

1. Design a table to store all information in one table like table below:

[image: table 1]

2. Design it as separated table:

[image: table 2-parent]

[image: table 2-child]

1. For the first approach, it is easy to find the data I need based on the criteria but if the criteria is too long, the column can take it and it will be harder for the system to separate the data.
2. For the second approach, maintaining is it easy but the parent table will become meaningless if the child does not exist. It is because they are depending on each other.

I would like to ask which is the best way to design the table for this approach. It should be ease for searching and maintaining. Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: To answer you statement *"the parent table will become meaningless if the child does not exist"*, why would you have a row in the parent table and not in the child, *unless* the parent has a value of `0` for the reward? If it does have a value, and there are no rows in the child table, it's not that the parent is "meaningless", it's that there's data missing in your table. You therefore need to ensure that that can't happen when populating your data. In all honestly though, I think the "parent" would be better as a view and you just need the "child" table (unless you can have no children).

Comment: I do need to make sure the child must have something in it so that, the parent won't stay there for nothing. I also worry about what if the reward giving is same but the criteria is not same. Meanings like we will have ID 1 and 2 is giving out 30 candies but the child table will not have the same criteria. By looking at the table itself, it does't give any meaning at all at this point. So is this approach good or not good?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't ever need to look at "stars" or "points" individually, then Design 1 is the better approach.

If you do need to look at these criteria individually, then Design 2 is absolutely the better approach.